# Is there a code pattern to return bcrypt hash created with async function to a separate module?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, bcrypt

Is there an elegant way to return a bcrypt hash value to a separate module?

In the example below function hashPassword() uses bcrypt to hash a password.  It is located in the file hashpassword.js.  I'd like to return its hash value to the variable myHashedPassword in app.js. I'm sure there must be a brute force way to do this.  But is there any sort of clever or elegant way to return the value?

**app.js**

```
let password = '123';
let myHashedPassword = hashPassword(password);
```

**hashpassword.js**

```
function hashPassword(password) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(error, hash) {
            // In most cases at this point hash is saved to the database.
            // However is there a pattern to return its value to the outer function and then app.js?
            // With this being async is that even possible?
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package has synchronous equivalents to the functions you are using, see [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-hash-a-password-1). If you still want to leverage the async versions, then you would need to return a `Promise` which you can then `await` e.g.

```
function hashPassword(password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (error, salt) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      bcrypt.hash(
        password, 
        salt, 
        (error, hash) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(hash)
      );
    }); 
  });
}
...
let hashed = await hashPassword(password);
```

In terms of then exporting in a way that the consumer simply calls the function, if using ES6 or newer

```
export default function hashPassword(password) {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise

```
function hashPassword(password) {
  ...
}

module.exports = hashPassword
```

Comment: That part is no problem.  I'm already exporting the function and using it in app.js.

Comment: @stackedAndOverflowed was in the middle of updating as I missed your original point (see update)

Comment: You are right, the sync function would work fine.  Unfortunately hashing burns up a lot of CPU and blocks things so I have to use async.  I see this is a duplicate.  I think my brain is going to have to stretch on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use out of the box non-blocking bcrypt functions with await/async:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
var hash = await bcrypt.hash(clear_text_password, salt);
```

Then to authenticate

```
const match = await bcrypt.compare(clear_text_password, hash);

if(match) { // do something awesome }
```